# How to simplify $2^{a}\mod{ab}$

Tags: calculus, modular-arithmetic

How to simplify $$2^{a}\mod{ab}$$

Where

- $a$ and $b$ are positive integers
- $a$ is a composite of relatively small primes.
- $b$ is very large and got no small primes and it's hard to be factored
- $a$ is very large in compare to $b$

At the moment I am running it in Java using BigInteger `2.modPow(a,ab)` and the program hangs